# How to ignore test files from execution in jest in nx framework

Tags: reactjs, regex, unit-testing, jestjs, nrwl-nx

We are running unit test cases in jest through the nx command :-  nx affected --target=test and We have certain test files like :-
1)abc.integration.spec.ts
2)abc.spec.ts

When I am running command :- **nx affected --target=test** , It is running both test cases.

Is there any way to ignore/avoid/skip "abc.integration.spec.ts" from unit test execution.?

**FYI** :- I have already used **testPathIgnorePatterns** flag through the command :-
`nx affected --target=test --testPathIgnorePatterns='integration.spec.ts'`, but it is still running both files. Looks like **testPathIgnorePatterns** is not supported in nx jest cli

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by modifying the jest.config.ts file and adding "testMatch", "testPathIgnorePatterns" or "testRegex". Consider that the order of precedence impacts whether the files are excluded or not.

For example, if you add:

```
testMatch: [
"!**/*.integration.spec.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts"
]
```

The second pattern cancels the first one. You have to write the negations at the end to make it work.

This will skip any test file that ends with `.integration.test.ts`, and if you want to run them separately, you'll have to add another command in the `project.json` and create a separated `jest.config.integration.ts`, including the integration tests and excluding any other .test file, and reference it there. That way, you could run your integration tests with `nx affected --target=integration` (if the new command is called "integration" of course)

Comment: Changing `jest.config.ts` won't work for me. The test won't get recognised as a test. I only want it to be ignored by `nx` framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `testPathIgnorePatterns` option in `project.json` file.

```
...
"test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/lmp-workers/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true,
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["^.*\\.integration\\..*$"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "ci": true,
          "codeCoverage": true
        }
      }
    },
...
```

The file will be recognized as a test for exmaple IDE like IntelliJ but it won't get picked up when you run test through nx command like `nx run projectName:test`